# Making a triangular button in Android

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

Is there any way to make an isosceles triangle that I can use as a button with Android?

This button takes up the entire screen:

[image]

Here is my current xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/main_menu_bg"
    >

     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal">

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/ai_button"
              android:background="@drawable/ai_button"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried using the ShapeDrawable to create a triangle that looks like the button I need, but I ShapeDrawable doesn't work, I tried making an ImageButton, but the button takes up the entire screen, I tried using a regular button but the button still takes up the entire screen, and I tried using an ImageView but it still does the same thing.

The button size is always too big and if I shrink the actual button size then the image itself shrinks inside and I can't figure out a way to stretch the image to fill either the View or the Button.

I have been trying to build this in Android Studio because the option to preview is super convenient, but if there is something I can use in Xamarin, or if there's something I can do programmatically, I'm open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xml

```
   <item android:top="45dp">
  <shape>
      <size android:height="100dp" android:width="90dp"/>
     <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
   </shape>
 </item>
       <item android:top="36dp" android:left="11dp">
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="45"
    android:toDegrees="0"
     android:pivotX="80%"
     android:pivotY="20%" >
     <shape>
         <size android:width="40dp"
            android:height="30dp"/>
           <stroke android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_light"             android:width="1dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

```
 Use it in your layout

 public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

private int mWidth;
private int mHeight;


public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {
    super(context, attrs);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

   super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.YourColor);

    mPaint.setColor(color);
    Path mPath = new Path();
    mPath.moveTo(.0f, this.getHeight());
    mPath.lineTo(0.8f * this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    mPath.lineTo(this.getWidth(), 0.5f * this.getHeight());
    mPath.lineTo(0.8f * this.getWidth(), .0f);
    mPath.lineTo(.0f, .0f);
    mPath.lineTo(.0f, this.getHeight());

    canvas.clipPath(mPath);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath,mPaint);


}
 }
```

Regarding the xml example | there are two rectangles overlapping.You             have to play around with the values a lot and this makes it difficult to use on different views. I think using a custom view is the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you have to measure screen height and know about how much (e.g. in percent) your button will cover. but you are getting here very bad aproach. sample: there are two devices with full HD display, one with physical buttons home/switch/back, second with on-screen - your bitmap will be streched on one of them, so you should also stretch your button properly... and you have `wrap_content` set for your `ImageView` so it will have "fixed" height regardless to vertically stretched background... don't go this way

edit: you may try weightSum param of LinearLayout for calculating "percentage" size of button. not so well, but might be what you need

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/main_menu_bg"
    >

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ai_button"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:src="@drawable/ai_button"
          android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```